# My postfix server rejects my python script - "Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname"

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, spam

I have a postfix on a server. When I'm trying to send an email from my python script, it gets rejected due to "Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname".

How to allow an email come through? If I merely remove a certain setting from the config of my postfix and thus relax the rules, spammers will take advantage of this.

My hostname and IP are dynamic, I move around often and I still want to be able to send emails this way.

the config of posfix:

```
compatibility_level = 2

# LOCAL PATHNAME INFORMATION
#
# The queue_directory specifies the location of the Postfix queue.
# This is also the root directory of Postfix daemons that run chrooted.
# See the files in examples/chroot-setup for setting up Postfix chroot
# environments on different UNIX systems.
#
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

# The command_directory parameter specifies the location of all
# postXXX commands.
#
command_directory = /usr/bin

# The daemon_directory parameter specifies the location of all Postfix
# daemon programs (i.e. programs listed in the master.cf file). This
# directory must be owned by root.
#
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/bin

# The data_directory parameter specifies the location of Postfix-writable
# data files (caches, random numbers). This directory must be owned
# by the mail_owner account (see below).
#
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

# QUEUE AND PROCESS OWNERSHIP
#
# The mail_owner parameter specifies the owner of the Postfix queue
# and of most Postfix daemon processes.  Specify the name of a user
# account THAT DOES NOT SHARE ITS USER OR GROUP ID WITH OTHER ACCOUNTS
# AND THAT OWNS NO OTHER FILES OR PROCESSES ON THE SYSTEM.  In
# particular, don't specify nobody or daemon. PLEASE USE A DEDICATED
# USER.
#
mail_owner = postfix

# The default_privs parameter specifies the default rights used by
# the local delivery agent for delivery to external file or command.
# These rights are used in the absence of a recipient user context.
# DO NOT SPECIFY A PRIVILEGED USER OR THE POSTFIX OWNER.
#
#default_privs = nobody

# The proxy_interfaces parameter specifies the network interface
# addresses that this mail system receives mail on by way of a
# proxy or network address translation unit. This setting extends
# the address list specified with the inet_interfaces parameter.
#
# You must specify your proxy/NAT addresses when your system is a
# backup MX host for other domains, otherwise mail delivery loops
# will happen when the primary MX host is down.
#
#proxy_interfaces =
#proxy_interfaces = 1.2.3.4

# The mydestination parameter specifies the list of domains that this
# machine considers itself the final destination for.
#
# These domains are routed to the delivery agent specified with the
# local_transport parameter setting. By default, that is the UNIX
# compatible delivery agent that lookups all recipients in /etc/passwd
# and /etc/aliases or their equivalent.
#
# The default is $myhostname + localhost.$mydomain + localhost.  On
# a mail domain gateway, you should also include $mydomain.
#
# Do not specify the names of virtual domains - those domains are
# specified elsewhere (see VIRTUAL_README).
#
# Do not specify the names of domains that this machine is backup MX
# host for. Specify those names via the relay_domains settings for
# the SMTP server, or use permit_mx_backup if you are lazy (see
# STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README).
#
# The local machine is always the final destination for mail addressed
# to user@[the.net.work.address] of an interface that the mail system
# receives mail on (see the inet_interfaces parameter).
#
# Specify a list of host or domain names, /file/name or type:table
# patterns, separated by commas and/or whitespace. A /file/name
# pattern is replaced by its contents; a type:table is matched when
# a name matches a lookup key (the right-hand side is ignored).
# Continue long lines by starting the next line with whitespace.
#
# See also below, section "REJECTING MAIL FOR UNKNOWN LOCAL USERS".
#
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
# mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

# REJECTING UNKNOWN RELAY USERS
#
# The relay_recipient_maps parameter specifies optional lookup tables
# with all addresses in the domains that match $relay_domains.
#
# If this parameter is defined, then the SMTP server will reject
# mail for unknown relay users. This feature is off by default.
#
# The right-hand side of the lookup tables is conveniently ignored.
# In the left-hand side, specify an @domain.tld wild-card, or specify
# a user@domain.tld address.
# 
#relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients

# ADDRESS REWRITING
#
# The ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document gives information about
# address masquerading or other forms of address rewriting including
# username->Firstname.Lastname mapping.

# ADDRESS REDIRECTION (VIRTUAL DOMAIN)
#
# The VIRTUAL_README document gives information about the many forms
# of domain hosting that Postfix supports.

# "USER HAS MOVED" BOUNCE MESSAGES
#
# See the discussion in the ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document.

# TRANSPORT MAP
#
# See the discussion in the ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document.

# ALIAS DATABASE
#
# The alias_maps parameter specifies the list of alias databases used
# by the local delivery agent. The default list is system dependent.
#
# On systems with NIS, the default is to search the local alias
# database, then the NIS alias database. See aliases(5) for syntax
# details.
# 
# If you change the alias database, run "postalias /etc/aliases" (or
# wherever your system stores the mail alias file), or simply run
# "newaliases" to build the necessary DBM or DB file.
#
# It will take a minute or so before changes become visible.  Use
# "postfix reload" to eliminate the delay.
#
#alias_maps = dbm:/etc/aliases
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
#alias_maps = netinfo:/aliases
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases

# The alias_database parameter specifies the alias database(s) that
# are built with "newaliases" or "sendmail -bi".  This is a separate
# configuration parameter, because alias_maps (see above) may specify
# tables that are not necessarily all under control by Postfix.
#
#alias_database = dbm:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = dbm:/etc/mail/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/opt/majordomo/aliases
#alias_database = $alias_maps

# ADDRESS EXTENSIONS (e.g., user+foo)
#
# The recipient_delimiter parameter specifies the separator between
# user names and address extensions (user+foo). See canonical(5),
# local(8), relocated(5) and virtual(5) for the effects this has on
# aliases, canonical, virtual, relocated and .forward file lookups.
# Basically, the software tries user+foo and .forward+foo before
# trying user and .forward.
#
#recipient_delimiter = +

# DELIVERY TO MAILBOX
#
# The home_mailbox parameter specifies the optional pathname of a
# mailbox file relative to a user's home directory. The default
# mailbox file is /var/spool/mail/user or /var/mail/user.  Specify
# "Maildir/" for qmail-style delivery (the / is required).
#
#home_mailbox = Mailbox
home_mailbox = Maildir/

# The mail_spool_directory parameter specifies the directory where
# UNIX-style mailboxes are kept. The default setting depends on the
# system type.
#
#mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
#mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail

# The mailbox_command parameter specifies the optional external
# command to use instead of mailbox delivery. The command is run as
# the recipient with proper HOME, SHELL and LOGNAME environment settings.
# Exception:  delivery for root is done as $default_user.
#
# Other environment variables of interest: USER (recipient username),
# EXTENSION (address extension), DOMAIN (domain part of address),
# and LOCAL (the address localpart).
#
# Unlike other Postfix configuration parameters, the mailbox_command
# parameter is not subjected to $parameter substitutions. This is to
# make it easier to specify shell syntax (see example below).
#
# Avoid shell meta characters because they will force Postfix to run
# an expensive shell process. Procmail alone is expensive enough.
#
# IF YOU USE THIS TO DELIVER MAIL SYSTEM-WIDE, YOU MUST SET UP AN
# ALIAS THAT FORWARDS MAIL FOR ROOT TO A REAL USER.
#
#mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail
#mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"

# The mailbox_transport specifies the optional transport in master.cf
# to use after processing aliases and .forward files. This parameter
# has precedence over the mailbox_command, fallback_transport and
# luser_relay parameters.
#
# Specify a string of the form transport:nexthop, where transport is
# the name of a mail delivery transport defined in master.cf.  The
# :nexthop part is optional. For more details see the sample transport
# configuration file.
#
# NOTE: if you use this feature for accounts not in the UNIX password
# file, then you must update the "local_recipient_maps" setting in
# the main.cf file, otherwise the SMTP server will reject mail for    
# non-UNIX accounts with "User unknown in local recipient table".
#
# Cyrus IMAP over LMTP. Specify ``lmtpunix      cmd="lmtpd"
# listen="/var/imap/socket/lmtp" prefork=0'' in cyrus.conf.
#mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/imap/socket/lmtp
#
# Cyrus IMAP via command line. Uncomment the "cyrus...pipe" and
# subsequent line in master.cf.
#mailbox_transport = cyrus

# The fallback_transport specifies the optional transport in master.cf
# to use for recipients that are not found in the UNIX passwd database.
# This parameter has precedence over the luser_relay parameter.
#
# Specify a string of the form transport:nexthop, where transport is
# the name of a mail delivery transport defined in master.cf.  The
# :nexthop part is optional. For more details see the sample transport
# configuration file.
#
# NOTE: if you use this feature for accounts not in the UNIX password
# file, then you must update the "local_recipient_maps" setting in
# the main.cf file, otherwise the SMTP server will reject mail for    
# non-UNIX accounts with "User unknown in local recipient table".
#
#fallback_transport = lmtp:unix:/file/name
#fallback_transport = cyrus
#fallback_transport =

# The luser_relay parameter specifies an optional destination address
# for unknown recipients.  By default, mail for unknown@$mydestination,
# unknown@[$inet_interfaces] or unknown@[$proxy_interfaces] is returned
# as undeliverable.
#
# The following expansions are done on luser_relay: $user (recipient
# username), $shell (recipient shell), $home (recipient home directory),
# $recipient (full recipient address), $extension (recipient address
# extension), $domain (recipient domain), $local (entire recipient
# localpart), $recipient_delimiter. Specify ${name?value} or
# ${name:value} to expand value only when $name does (does not) exist.
#
# luser_relay works only for the default Postfix local delivery agent.
#
# NOTE: if you use this feature for accounts not in the UNIX password
# file, then you must specify "local_recipient_maps =" (i.e. empty) in
# the main.cf file, otherwise the SMTP server will reject mail for    
# non-UNIX accounts with "User unknown in local recipient table".
#
#luser_relay = $user@other.host
#luser_relay = $local@other.host
#luser_relay = admin+$local

# JUNK MAIL CONTROLS
# 
# The controls listed here are only a very small subset. The file
# SMTPD_ACCESS_README provides an overview.

# The header_checks parameter specifies an optional table with patterns
# that each logical message header is matched against, including
# headers that span multiple physical lines.
#
# By default, these patterns also apply to MIME headers and to the
# headers of attached messages. With older Postfix versions, MIME and
# attached message headers were treated as body text.
#
# For details, see "man header_checks".
#
#header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

# FAST ETRN SERVICE
#
# Postfix maintains per-destination logfiles with information about
# deferred mail, so that mail can be flushed quickly with the SMTP
# "ETRN domain.tld" command, or by executing "sendmail -qRdomain.tld".
# See the ETRN_README document for a detailed description.
# 
# The fast_flush_domains parameter controls what destinations are
# eligible for this service. By default, they are all domains that
# this server is willing to relay mail to.
# 
#fast_flush_domains = $relay_domains

# SHOW SOFTWARE VERSION OR NOT
#
# The smtpd_banner parameter specifies the text that follows the 220
# code in the SMTP server's greeting banner. Some people like to see
# the mail version advertised. By default, Postfix shows no version.
#
# You MUST specify $myhostname at the start of the text. That is an
# RFC requirement. Postfix itself does not care.
#
#smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
#smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name ($mail_version)

# DEBUGGING CONTROL
#
# The debug_peer_level parameter specifies the increment in verbose
# logging level when an SMTP client or server host name or address
# matches a pattern in the debug_peer_list parameter.
#
debug_peer_level = 2

# when a Postfix daemon program is run with the -D option.
#
# Use "command .. & sleep 5" so that the debugger can attach before
# the process marches on. If you use an X-based debugger, be sure to
# set up your XAUTHORITY environment variable before starting Postfix.
#
debugger_command =
   PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
   ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

# INSTALL-TIME CONFIGURATION INFORMATION
#
# The following parameters are used when installing a new Postfix version.
# 
# sendmail_path: The full pathname of the Postfix sendmail command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible mail posting interface.
# 
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/sendmail

# newaliases_path: The full pathname of the Postfix newaliases command.
# This is the Sendmail-compatible command to build alias databases.
#
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases

# mailq_path: The full pathname of the Postfix mailq command.  This
# is the Sendmail-compatible mail queue listing command.
# 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq

# setgid_group: The group for mail submission and queue management
# commands.  This must be a group name with a numerical group ID that
# is not shared with other accounts, not even with the Postfix account.
#
setgid_group = postdrop

# html_directory: The location of the Postfix HTML documentation.
#
html_directory = no

# manpage_directory: The location of the Postfix on-line manual pages.
#
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

# sample_directory: The location of the Postfix sample configuration files.
# This parameter is obsolete as of Postfix 2.1.
#
sample_directory = /etc/postfix

# readme_directory: The location of the Postfix README files.
#
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
inet_protocols = ipv4
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix

compatibility_level = 2

# disable "new mail" notifications for local unix users
biff = no

# directory to store mail for local unix users
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail/local

# Name of this mail server, used in the SMTP HELO for outgoing mail. Make
# sure this resolves to the same IP as your reverse DNS hostname.
myhostname = mail.my_postfix_server.com
mydomain = my_postfix_server.com

# Domains for which postfix will deliver local mail. Does not apply to
# virtual domains, which are configured below. Make sure to specify the FQDN
# of your sever, as well as localhost.
# Note: NEVER specify any virtual domains here!!! Those come later.
#mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
mydestination = $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

# Domain appended to mail sent locally from this machine - such as mail sent
# via the `sendmail` command.
myorigin = $mydomain

# prevent spammers from searching for valid users
disable_vrfy_command = yes

# require properly formatted email addresses - prevents a lot of spam
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes

# don't give any helpful info when a mailbox doesn't exist
show_user_unknown_table_name = no

# limit maximum e-mail size to 50MB. mailbox size must be at least as big as
# the message size for the mail to be accepted, but has no meaning after
# that since we are using Dovecot for delivery.
message_size_limit = 51200000
mailbox_size_limit = 0

# require addresses of the form "user@domain.tld"
allow_percent_hack = no
swap_bangpath = no

# allow plus-aliasing: "user+tag@domain.tld" delivers to "user" mailbox
recipient_delimiter = +

# path to the SSL certificate for the mail server
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.my_postfix_server.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.my_postfix_server.com/privkey.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_enforce_tls = yes

# I have two certificates - one is RSA, the other uses the newer ECC. ECC is
# faster and arguably more secure, but many mail servers don't yet support
# it. I enable both types in postfix, but you most likely only have a single
# RSA cert, and don't need to include these three lines.
#smtpd_tls_eccert_file = /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/mail.example.com.ecc.crt
#smtpd_tls_eckey_file = /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/mail.example.com.ecc.key
#smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = ultra

# Path to your trusted certificates file. Usually provided by a
# ca-certificates package or similar.
#smtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/ssl/cert.pem

# These two lines define how postfix will connect to other mail servers.
# DANE is a stronger form of opportunistic TLS. You can read about it here:
# http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_dane
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
# DANE requires a DNSSEC capable resolver. If your DNS resolver doesn't
# support DNSSEC, remove the above two lines and uncomment the below:
#   smtp_tls_security_level = may


# Here we define the options for "mandatory" TLS. In our setup, TLS is only
# "mandatory" for authenticating users. I got these settings from Mozilla's
# SSL reccomentations page.
#
# NOTE: do not attempt to make TLS mandatory for all incoming/outgoing
# connections. Do not attempt to change the default cipherlist for non-
# mandatory connections either. There are still a lot of mail servers out
# there that do not use TLS, and many that do only support old ciphers.
# Forcing TLS for everyone *will* cause you to lose mail.
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

# allow other mail servers to connect using TLS, but don't require it
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

# tickets and compression have known vulnerabilities
tls_ssl_options = no_ticket, no_compression

# it's more secure to generate your own DH params
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file  = /etc/ssl/dh512.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh2048.pem

# cache incoming and outgoing TLS sessions
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_tlscache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database  = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_tlscache

# enable SMTPD auth. Dovecot will place an `auth` socket in postfix's
# runtime directory that we will use for authentication.
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot

# only allow authentication over TLS
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

# don't allow plaintext auth methods on unencrypted connections
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
# but plaintext auth is fine when using TLS
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

# add a message header when email was recieved over TLS
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes

# require that connecting mail servers identify themselves - this greatly
# reduces spam
smtpd_helo_required = yes

# The following block specifies some security restrictions for incoming
# mail. The gist of it is, authenticated users and connections from
# localhost can do anything they want. Random people connecting over the
# internet are treated with more suspicion: they must have a reverse DNS
# entry and present a valid, FQDN HELO hostname. In addition, they can only
# send mail to valid mailboxes on the server, and the sender's domain must
# actually exist.
smtpd_client_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  warn_if_reject reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname

  # you might want to consider:
  reject_unknown_client_hostname
  # here. This will reject all incoming connections without a reverse DNS
  # entry that resolves back to the client's IP address. This is a very
  # restrictive check and may reject legitimate mail.

  reject_unauth_pipelining
  reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
  reject_unauth_pipelining
  reject_invalid_helo_hostname
  reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
  reject_rbl_client pbl.spamhaus.org
  reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org
  reject_rbl_client bl.blocklist.de
  reject_unknown_client 

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,

  # you might want to consider:
  #  reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
  # here. This will reject all incoming mail without a HELO hostname that
  # properly resolves in DNS. This is a somewhat restrictive check and may
  # reject legitimate mail.
  reject_unauth_pipelining

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks

###
  reject_sender_login_mismatch
###

  permit_sasl_authenticated
  reject_non_fqdn_sender
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
  reject_unauth_pipelining
  reject_unknown_address

smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,

  # !!! THIS SETTING PREVENTS YOU FROM BEING AN OPEN RELAY !!!
  reject_unauth_destination
  # !!!      DO NOT REMOVE IT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES      !!!


smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
  reject_invalid_hostname,
  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
  reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
  permit

smtpd_data_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_multi_recipient_bounce,
  reject_unauth_pipelining

# deliver mail for virtual users to Dovecot's LMTP socket
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

#  query to find which domains we accept mail for
virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf

# query to find which email addresses we accept mail for
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

# query to find a user's email aliases
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps.cf

virtual_alias_domains = 
alias_database = 
alias_maps = 

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = all
```

master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${user}@${nexthop} ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop}

smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no



submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Comment: You need to authenticate and send on port 587, not send on port 25.

Comment: @MichaelHampton still the same error

Comment: OK, what is your postfix configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton updated

Comment: @MichaelHampton what do you say?

Comment: Just to be sure, run a " postconf | grep smtpd_client_restrictions " to see that the settings are active.  Then post some lines in the logfile, where it show that you are using SASL login to post a message. But... If you check Your config, the lines  " ### " in the middle of the "client_restrictions" statement. I dont think it is allowed to have comments there. Comments must be outside a configuration line. (ending with a comma ",".
Verify with "postconf"

Comment: Do you have a different configuration for submission in master.cf? This should be fine as is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton added